# Overwrite stack-allocated instance of a class

Tags: c++, memory, c++17

Consider the following code:

```cpp
class A{
    
  public:
    A(){};
    
};

int main(){
    
    A a = A();
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;
    
    a = A();
    std::cout << &a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Both addresses are the same. The behavior that I expected was that the second call to `A()` would overwrite the variable `a` by creating a new instance of A, thereby changing the new address of `a`.

Why is this so? Is there a way to statically overwrite `a` that I am not aware of?

Thank you!

Comment: `thereby changing the new address of a.` _Why_ do you expect the address to change?

Comment: When you park a new car in your garage, does the garage change the address?

Comment: Its the same as `int x =1 ;`  then a few line later `x = 7;` you don't expect x to be at a new location in that case do you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is this so?

Within the scope of its lifetime, a variable is exactly one complete object (except in the case of recursion in which case there are multiple overlapping instances of the variable). `a` here is the same object from its declaration until the return of the function.

> I expected was that the second call to A() would overwrite the variable a by creating a new instance of A,

It did that.

> thereby changing the new address of a.

It didn't do that. The temporary object created by `A()` had a new address, but that temporary object was destroyed at the end of that full expression. `a` remained where it had been, and you invoked its assignment operator with the temporary object as the argument.

Answer (score 0):

The variable a is allocated on the stack.  Its address is not going to change for the duration of the function.  The first and the second instance of class A will be created in the space taken up but the variable.